# how to display pin on current location in android google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am using intent for finding the route between two geopoints on the map in android,I am getting pin on the destination point but nit getting pin on my source locatio,Please tell me how can i do that,My code is as below:
**code**

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + currentLatitude
                    + "," + currentLongitude + "&daddr=" + lat + "," + lng;
            i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
                    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you directly navigate `Official Google Maps` the it'll display Pins on both Locations. try below another way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat + ","+ lng + "&daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude + ""));
startActivity(intent);
```